# Retrieve one row from 1 to many relationship between three tables

Tags: sql, subquery, aggregate, relationship

I have the following three tables:

#### ----PRODUCT----

```
PRODUCT_ID     DESC     
1              'Pencil'   
2              'Paper'
```

#### ----PRICE_BY_SUPPLIER----

```
PRODUCT_ID     SUPPLIER_ID     PRICE  
1              1               10  
1              2               9  
1              3               9.5  
2              1               5
```

#### ----IMAGES_BY_PRODUCT----

```
PRODUCT_ID     NAME  
1              'pencil.img'  
1              'pen.img'  
1              'pencil_other.img'  
2              'paper.img'
```

I would like a query that pull the minimum price, the count of supplier that hold the product and one image (one image among all suppliers).  The output query should look like this:

#### ----FINAL_QUERY----

```
PRODUCT_ID     MIN_PRICE     IMAGE          SUPPLIER_COUNT  
1              9             'pencil.img'   3  
2              5             'paper.img'    1
```

I have this query that return everything except the image.

```
SELECT f.PRODUCT_ID, f.DESC, x.MIN_PRICE, x.SUPPLIER_COUNT  
  FROM (
        SELECT pp.PRODUCT_ID, 
               MIN(pp.PRICE) AS MIN_PRICE, 
               COUNT(pp.PRODUCT_ID) AS SUPPLIER_COUNT 
          FROM PRICE_BY_SUPPLIER AS pp 
         GROUP 
            BY pp.PRODUCT_ID
       )   
       AS x
       INNER JOIN PRODUCT AS f 
         ON f.PRODUCT_ID = X.PRODUCT_ID
```

Can you help me complete my query ?

Comment: Which SQL product? For `PRODUCT_ID = 1` there are three images. You need to specify in the SQL which you want (MAX, MIN, random, arbitrary, etc) and how you code this will depend on the  SQL product you are targeting (unless you are looking for Standard SQL only).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than get involved with all those horrific joins, couldn't you try something like...

```
SELECT PRODUCT_ID,
       (SELECT MIN(PRICE)
             FROM PRICE_BY_SUPPLIER
             WHERE PRICE_BY_SUPPLIER.PRODUCT_ID = PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID) AS MIN_PRICE,
       (SELECT NAME
             FROM PRODUCT_IMAGES
             WHERE PRODUCT_IMAGES.PRODUCT_ID = PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID
             LIMIT 1) AS PRODUCT_IMAGES,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
             FROM PRICE_BY_SUPPLIER
             WHERE PRICE_BY_SUPPLIER.PRODUCT_ID = PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID) AS SUPPLIER_COUNT
    FROM PRODUCT_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add another join to fetch an image.  For example, the `max` image per productid:

```
SELECT  f.PRODUCT_ID, f.DESC, x.MIN_PRICE, x.SUPPLIER_COUNT, img.Name
FROM    ( 
        select  pp.PRODUCT_ID
        ,       MIN(pp.PRICE) as MIN_PRICE
        ,       COUNT(pp.PRODUCT_ID) as SUPPLIER_COUNT 
        from    PRICE_BY_SUPPLIER as pp 
        group by 
                pp.PRODUCT_ID
        ) AS x 
JOIN    PRODUCT as f 
on      f.PRODUCT_ID = X.PRODUCT_ID
JOIN    (
        select  max(name)
        from    images_by_product
        group by
                product_id
        ) as img
on      img.PRODUCT_ID = X.PRODUCT_ID
```

If the image is optional, replace the `join` with an `outer join`.  Depending on your DBMS, you can also fetch a random image.  For example, in SQL Server, you could replace the join with `cross apply`:

```
...
on      f.PRODUCT_ID = X.PRODUCT_ID
CROSS APPLY
        (
        select  top 1 name
        from    images_by_product
        where   PRODUCT_ID = X.PRODUCT_ID
        order by
                newid()
        ) as img
```

Or even directly in the select clause:

```
SELECT  f.PRODUCT_ID, f.DESC, x.MIN_PRICE, x.SUPPLIER_COUNT, img.Name
,       (
        select  top 1 name
        from    images_by_product
        where   PRODUCT_ID = X.PRODUCT_ID
        order by
                newid()
        ) as img
FROM    ( 
        select  pp.PRODUCT_ID
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.product_id, MIN(pbs.price), ibp.name, pbs.supplier_id
FROM product p
INNER JOIN price_by_supplier pbs
ON  p.product_id = pbs.product_id
INNER JOIN images_by_product ibp
ON p.product_id = ibp.product_id
GROUP BY p.product_id
```

I was able to get your exact output (other than the supplier_count as that didn't make sense to me.  Please explain further if you could.

```
PRODUCT_ID     MIN_PRICE     IMAGE          SUPPLIER_ID  
1              9             'pencil.img'   1  
2              5             'paper.img'    1
```

**UPDATED:**

This is kind of a lame way to get what you want but...  It does work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.product_id, MIN(pbs.price), ibp.name, COUNT(pbs.supplier_id)
FROM product p
INNER JOIN images_by_product ibp
ON p.product_id = ibp.product_id
INNER JOIN price_by_supplier pbs
ON  p.product_id = pbs.product_id
GROUP BY  pbs.price
LIMIT 2


PRODUCT_ID     MIN_PRICE     IMAGE          SUPPLIER_ID  
2              5             'paper.img'     1  
1              9             'pencil.img'    3
```